# Node.js Route to Controller not applying Controller constructor

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I have an express.js application that uses the `express.Router()` to connect my endpoints to controllers.

My goal is to have an object newed up in the controller constructor so I can use it in all controller functions without having to new it up in each one.

The constructor runs correct, and the object is available within the constructor. But whenever I call any actions of the controller, the object is null.

Here is the router

```
const express = require('express');
const componentController = require('../controllers/component');

const router = express.Router();

// component routes
router.get('/components', componentController.getComponents);

module.exports = router;
```

And here is my controller.

```
const LogService = require('../services/logService');

class ComponentController {
    constructor() {
        this.logger = new LogService('ComponentController');
        this.logger.logDebug('test1','test1');
    }

    async getComponents(req, res) {
        const test = new LogService('ComponentController');
        test.logDebug('test2','test2');

        this.logger.logDebug('test3','test3')
        res.json('');
    }
}

module.exports = new ComponentController();
```

I want the LogService to be available in the controller actions. The first two logs work correctly, `test1` and `test2`. But `test3` throws an error saying logger is undefined.

Why is `this.logger` undefined in later functions? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: try to refactor `getComponents` to an arrow function

Comment: Thanks that did it, can you explain why that fixed it or is it just some magic? `getComponents = async (req, res) => `

Comment: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/this-binding-in-es6-arrow-function-70d80e216238

Comment: If you want to make your comment an answer I can accept it.

Comment: thx, posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to refactor `getComponents` to an arrow function.

Here is why: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/this-binding-in-es6-arrow-function-70d80e216238

You can also do this:

```
router.get('/components', componentController.getComponents.bind(componentController));
```